# why is the 3rd argument to cv::Dilate failing?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I am testing out erode and dilate functions in openCV2.2 but compilation fails because of the 3rd argument when I pass the following line:

```
dilate(gscaleImage, gscaleImage, 0, 18 );
```

can anyone shed a light on this for me please as this is how they've been coded in the examples.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV has both C and C++ interfaces. You're calling the C++ function cv::dilate but, judging by the arguments, it was actually meant to be cvDilate from the old-style C interface.

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenCV Documentation (sorry for the formatting):

> void dilate(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, const Mat& element, Point anchor=Point(-1, -1), int iterations=1, int borderType=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=morphologyDefaultBorderValue())

The third argument is `const Mat& element`, which is definitely not an `int` like 0. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

For iterations, I'd do:

```
dilate(gscaleImage, gscaleImage, 0, iterations = 18);
```

Comment: I'm learning openCV functions and how they work so I just wanted to do a simple dilate of an image. Upon finding the right reference for the function (I kept looking at the C version without realizing) I'm going to try and fix it now and see if it works. Also would your 3rd argument not fail as I'm using the c++ function?

Comment: Sorry, I code in Python. I didn't know C++ didn't accept default arguments like that...